# What are the potential vulnerabilities of sending HTML/JS to the browser from the database?

Tags: web-application, javascript, sql-server

An in-house team is creating a new framework and I'm not so sure it's as secure as they're letting on. I'm not super well versed in security so I wanted to ask for opinions.

A demo web app was created for us to get familiar with the layout. I don't have access to the source code yet, however when I viewed the network requests I saw HTML and JavaScript code being sent to the browser from the database. Among the code is a bunch of `script` tags that are being inserted and executed. The response is being placed into the DOM with `jQuery.load()` and no other means of validation or sanitizing on the browser. This is happening with almost every request that goes to the database.

Are there any kind of attacks that can come from this?

Comment: I think you misunderstand what it means for something to come out of the database. Do you mean that script tags are being loaded from the server and placed on the page? That is not terribly unusual

Comment: Also, sanitization usually is done on the server, not in the browser.

Comment: I think there may be some confusion around terminology here.  HTTP requests don't go to a database, they go to a web server.  You might try comparing what you see from this app to what you see from an Internet website, and I suspect you'll not see much difference.

Comment: there's nothing about bits stored in a DB that's more dangerous than bits stored in a file. It's _who_ those bits come from that makes all the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your demo web application connects directly to the database using some sort of client side code (which it is very unlikely and nothing in your question suggests that), what you are seeing is probably just regular browser to web server traffic (i.e. not the database), which will certainly include plenty of HTML and JavaScript. This is how it's meant to work.